# Build prod build for NextJs - (Static) automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, deployment, build

Trying to create prod build with npm run build

but it outputs to

info  - Creating an optimized production build
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data
info  - Generating static pages (5/5)
info  - Finalizing page optimization Page                                       Size     First Load JS

- List item

┌ ○ /
261 B           222 kB

├   /_app                                  0 B             222 kB

├ ○ /404                                   194 B           222 kB

├ ○ /dashboard                             236 B           222 kB

└ ○ /sign-in                               514 B           222 kB

- First Load JS shared by all              222 kB

  ├ chunks/framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js   42 kB

  ├ chunks/main-c586b89e07064d4a.js        27.9 kB

  ├ chunks/pages/_app-ff5b9dd4b852de7e.js  150 kB

  └ chunks/webpack-d3b4bbaea9693629.js     1.72 kB

○(Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)

What is missing here? i dont see any build folder in project root, also is it successfull or not?

tried to npm run build

Expecting  : successfull build and build folder in project root

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The "normal" output folder after `next build` would be `/.next`, which is not supposed to be touched during normal development, but instead should be used automatically by next.js with its included server, usually started with [`next start`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started#manual-setup).

Alternatively you can create a static build with [`next export`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export), and specify a custom output folder, but you have to setup a server yourself then.

Answer (score 0):

To enable a static export, change the output mode inside `next.config.js`:

```js
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
 
}
 
module.exports = nextConfig
```

After running `next build`, Next.js will produce an `out` folder which contains the HTML/CSS/JS assets for your application.

For reference check out the [Next JS Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).